# Any technique for linearization, or linear approximation?

Tags: linear-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Consider the following Matrix constraint:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} -U+\psi\Sigma_b^{-1} & V \\ V^T  & -V^TU^{-1}V+\tau_2 -\psi \end{bmatrix} \leq 0
$$
where $\Sigma_b$ is a known positive definite matrix (shape matrix of saturation bound). $U \geq 0 \in \mathbb{S}_{+}^{ n \times n} $ and $V \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\tau_2,\psi >0 \in \mathbb{R}$ are the decision variables. I can propose the following linearization technique for the problem.
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0  & -V^TU^{-1}V \end{bmatrix} \leq \begin{bmatrix} U-\psi\Sigma_b^{-1} & -V \\ -V^T  & -\tau_2 +\psi \end{bmatrix}
$$
as the left hand side is surely negative semi definite we can replace the original nonlinear constraint with the following linear constraint.
$$
\begin{bmatrix} U-\psi\Sigma_b^{-1} & -V \\ -V^T  & -\tau_2 +\psi \end{bmatrix} \geq 0
$$
But this linearization has conservatism which is generated from ignoring the features of term $V^TU^{-1}V$ and its impacts on the problem. So I wanted to ask do you guys have any suggestion for improving this linearization process?

Comment: What are we approximating?

Comment: My first aim is to find a linear equivallent to this constraint, but if that is impossible, I am interested in a linear constraint which is a good approximation of this nonlinear constraint.

Comment: I don't think there is an y (exact) linearization given that Y and y are both variables. That is a (non-convex) nonlinear semidefinite constraint. Any linear approximation would be at best locally "valid".

Comment: I am pretty sure it is convex even if it is not linear. because I replaced $y^T Y^{-1}y$ with a new variable $s$ and solved the optimization. and then updated $s$ with the solution of $Y$ and $y$. I witnessed the solution of this itereative approach always converges to a unique solution no matter what I selected as the initial condition for $s$.

Comment: That's not as proof of comvexity. An alternating variable scheme, as you seem to be describing, is a possible solution technique. I don't think it will generally come with a guarantee of converging to anything, let alone a global, or even local minimum. Nevertheless, if your computational experience with that approach is favorable, it may be that it works well in your case

Comment: Thanks Mark, for the valuable comment

Comment: Hi Mark, I have changed my question to this new one, do you have any suggestion for improvement?